# Any way to get back Chrome's Dialog box for cache clearing instead of the new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

As of today's release of chrome (Tuesday, March 8, 2011) on both Mac & PC the settings are now in a tab (chrome://settings/advanced), needless to say when you're clearing your cache very frequently (cmd-shift-delete on mac, cntl+shift+delete on PC) it's quite tedious going back and forth in tabs.  The click & clean chrome extension doesn't have a mac counterpart (plus I like the keyboard much more than the mouse).  I've searched and have yet to find a way to get a dialog box instead of the new tab.

Comment: I do not know :) But I have one helpful tip, start Chrome with --disk-cache-size=1 switch, which will cause Chrome to not use cache. Make shortcut, and use that Chrome when you need frequent clearing of cache. Hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

The Clear Browsing Data overlay does not work and is a known issue, and they're working on fixing it. Even so, it's still not as convenient as the dialog was.

You can start Chrome with the `--disabled-tabbed-options` command-line argument to use dialog options instead of the tabbed options. You'll have to add it to the command-line in your Chrome shortcuts.